# Check if string exists in list of strings in C#

Tags: c#, string, linq

Hello I am trying to find best and most efficient way to preform if string exists in list of strings.

My scenario is like this:

1. Get all string values from database that are satisfying given conditions.
2. Create random code that has 6 digits, but it is a string value.
3. Check if generated code exists in list of strings. If it does preform generating of code again, and do it until you find unique string that does not exists in list of strings. When you find one, return it.

This is my code:

```
private static readonly string chars = "0123456789";

string IGenerateOtpCodeService.GenerateOtpCode()
{
    var otps = personalTestSessionRepository
        .FindAll(x => x.State == PersonalTestSessionStates.NotStarted)
        .Select(x => x.Person.Otp)
        .ToList()
        .Distinct();

    Random random = new Random();

    string otp = new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, 6)
        .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());

    //preform check if otp exitst in otps list. if it does, generate otp again, else return otp
    return otp;
}
```

What is best way to do this? Is it while loop, some LINQ expresion, or something else?

Comment: So you basically want to get a number which is not already stored in the database? I´d suggest a different approach than randomly picking one as this might take very long when most numbers are already used. Why not simply order all the *existing* numbers and take the last one +1?

Comment: @GiladGreen I just select values from database, put them into list of strings. Then I want to generate new string, but I don't want that generated string exists in list. In other words I do not want to write same value into database. That's why I need to preform check: Is new generated string exists in list? Yes -> Generate new one (check again if it exists in list and so on), until I find unique string that doesn't exists in the list. In that case return that string. (and later in code it will be written into db).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `Distinct` before `ToList` to perform `Distinct` operation on database server. Then you can check existence of string using `Any`.

```
var otps = personalTestSessionRepository
    .FindAll(x => x.State == PersonalTestSessionStates.NotStarted)
    .Select(x => x.Person.Otp)
    .Distinct();
    .ToList();

string otp = null;
var found = true; 
do
{
    otp = new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, 6)
    .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());

    found = otps.Any(x=>x == otp);

} while(found)

return otp;
```

Based on heinzbeinz suggestion, the code will perform faster if you use `HashSet`. To use `HashSet`, use code below

```
var otpsList = personalTestSessionRepository
    .FindAll(x => x.State == PersonalTestSessionStates.NotStarted)
    .Select(x => x.Person.Otp)
    .Distinct();
    .ToList();

var otps = new HashSet<string>(otpsList);

string otp = null;
var found = true; 
do
{
    otp = new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, 6)
    .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());

    found = otps.Contains(otp);

} while(found)

return otp;
```

Comment: I would recommend using a `HashSet` with contains instead of a `List` for otps. Otherwise nice answer!

Comment: @heinzbeinz yes, it will perform faster. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of looking again and again *until* a value does not exist, why not simply reverse the logic and take all the numbers that already *exist* in your database? Order them and increment the greatest one by one to get a number that doesn´t exist:

```
var ordered = personalTestSessionRepository
    .FindAll(x => x.State == PersonalTestSessionStates.NotStarted)
    .Select(x => x.Person.Otp)
    .Order(x => x);

var newNumber = ordered.Last().Otp + 1;
```

Or when `Otp` is a string convert to a number first:

```
var newNumber = (Convert.ToInt32(ordered.Last().Otp) + 1).ToString();
```

This approach might be faster when nearly all numbers are already in use, so guessing any arbitrary one might take quite long as you may guess the same number multiple times.

EDIT: Alternativly you may simply use `Max(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Otp)) + 1`.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, searching in a `List` has `O(N)` time complexity when in case of `HashSet` is just `O(1)`:

```
 var ops = new HashSet<int>(personalTestSessionRepository
   .FindAll(x => x.State == PersonalTestSessionStates.NotStarted)
   .Select(x => x.Person.Otp));
```

Next, put `Random` off the method (or yor can have it badly skewed). 
Let's work with `Random` as `integer` and only then turn it into `String`

```
 // Simplest, but not thread safe
 private static Random random = new Random();

 string IGenerateOtpCodeService.GenerateOtpCode() {
   var ops = new HashSet<int>(personalTestSessionRepository
     .FindAll(x => x.State == PersonalTestSessionStates.NotStarted)
     .Select(x => x.Person.Otp));

   int value = -1;

   while (true) {
     value = random.Next(10000000);

     if (!ops.Contains(value)) 
       return value.ToString();
   }
 }
```

If you want just any number, not necessarily *random* one, you can look for a just *first hole*:

```
string IGenerateOtpCodeService.GenerateOtpCode() {
   var ops = personalTestSessionRepository
     .FindAll(x => x.State == PersonalTestSessionStates.NotStarted)
     .Select(x => x.Person.Otp)
     .OrderBy(x => x);

   bool first = true;
   int prior = -1;

   foreach (var item in ops) {
     if (!first && item != prior + 1)
       return item.ToString();

     first = false;
     prior = item; 
   }    

   // no holes, we might want to return the last item + 1
   return (prior + 1).ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, depending on the number of the strings in the database the best option might be to find it right there in db, instead of loading all of the data to the client and searching for the string afterwards. Yes, this might be easier to write, but if you have lots of strings then you should query the database for it. Of course you should have appropriate index to ensure it's fast.

Answer (score 0):

Add while loop

```
    while (true)
    {
        string otp = new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, 6)
        .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());

        if (otps.Contains(otp))
        {
            return otp;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to sort the list in the database.
When you have the sorted list, you can simply use Binary search for checking if the string exist.